# Alternatives to User Defined Performance Counters for CPU Monitoring - SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transparent-data-encryption, cpu

I want to monitor CPU usage before implementing TDE on several production SQL Servers.

My plan was to use user defined performance counters, over a period of a couple of days, counters as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/monitor-cpu-usage?view=sql-server-2017

I can view data on these counters when just looking at the Performance Monitor graph but the Data Collector sets just show datetime stamps and no counter data.

I'm on a time sensitive project and so I am looking for an alternative to perfmon.... and any advice.

I suppose the cause of the empty counters belongs on serverfault - but I would appreciate a solution if anyone ran into this issue and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - the issue is I tried running perfom not locally to the server but from another server. Locally it works. (sigh)